# How to insert the line break for field name in list view? (Odoo 13)

Tags: xml, treeview, odoo, line-breaks, odoo-13

I have a list view with many fields name label like this:

[image]

I want to insert the line break to show fully fields name in the list view. I'd tried to add \n in python. But it still not worked.

My python code:

```
thoigian = fields.Date('Khoảng thời gian', default=datetime.today(), required=True)
md_bhxh = fields.Float('Mức đóng BHXH')
md_bhtn = fields.Float('Mức đóng BHTN')
bhxhnld = fields.Float('(BHXH) % \n của NLĐ')
bhxhcty = fields.Float('(BHXH) % \n của Cty')    
bhtnnld = fields.Float('(BHTN) % của NLĐ')
bhtncty = fields.Float('(BHTN) % của Cty')    
bhytnld = fields.Float('(BHYT) % của NLĐ')
bhytcty = fields.Float('(BHYT) % của Cty')
```

My XML file:

```
  <record id="lich_su_thay_doi_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">lich.su.thay.doi.tree.view</field>
        <field name="model">lich.su</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Nhân viên" default_order="create_date desc">
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="thoigian"/>
                <field name="md_bhxh"/>
                <field name="md_bhtn"/>
                <field name="bhxhnld"/>
                <field name="bhxhcty"/>
                <field name="bhytnld"/>
                <field name="bhytcty"/>
                <field name="bhtnnld"/>
                <field name="bhtncty"/>
                <field name="loai"/>
                <field name="thamchieu"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

So how to insert the line break for fields name label in list view?

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can archive this goal.

- Firstly: show less field in view. From odoo 13+ there is a way to hide/show more columns,
- Secondly (better, but harder): Odoo use some css/scss styling in assets_backend, you can try to inherit this view, add your own css style sheet to change all view, or better create a new widget.

Comment: I agree with the second solution, writing a custom CSS might help. Find open source backend theme modules, that might give you an idea on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you, Nhat. I will try with the widget.